# XMLSchema: Is it possible to calculate how valid an invalid document is (eg. as a percentage)?

Tags: xml, xsd, lxml, xmllint

I'm using `lxml` in Python to validate a number of XML documents against an XML Schema definition. A good number of these documents do not validate -- and at the moment they're not expected to -- but it would be useful if I could calculate how valid they are, as a percentage, for reporting purposes. I have the ability to use `xmllint` or other command line tools, should those be able to provide a useful statistic.

Answer (score 1):

`lxml` parsers provide a way to get [a list of the errors](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#error-log) that occurred while trying to parse the document.  Combine this with the parser's [`recover` keyword argument](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options) and you get something like this:

```
# Warning, untested, may not work
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
it_would_be_a_tree = etree.parse(your_xml_data, parser)
total_errors = len(parser.error_log)
```

Then you can calculate the percentage of the file that `total_errors` represents. You could use a naive measure, like errors per line or errors per character without any trouble.  More sophisticated measures are also possible if `it_would_be_a_tree` is actually a `tree` structure (`total_elements / total_errors`, for example).

Comment: It's not the parsing that's the problem; the files parse fine, as they're well-formed xml. They're just not *valid* in relation to the XMLSchema.